# How to refresh remote file in PhpDesigner

Tags: phpdesigner

Usually I am working alone, but now I have a new colleague, so we need to work together.

Unfortunately we suffer the lack of git, so because of certain circumstance we need to work directly on FTP.

I am using Netbeans, but I recommended to her the PhpDesigner, because I know, it is working with files directly on the remote server, not like Netbeans what is make a local copy of the file.

When I edit a file, I tell it to her, so she close the file, and open it again, and my changes are appears.

I there any way to not close the file, just "refresh" it (download from server)?

Comment: Use any web based framework

Comment: How the framework related to IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't in phpDesigner, I've tried many ways but is not possible. You can do it in Npp.

Comment: what a shame for such an IDE